# Not able to login after installing fingerprint ubuntu 17.04

Tags: login, fingerprint-reader

I am trying to get my fingerprint on my thinkpad p51 to work. However, some packages were seen as a duplicate and therefore libfprint could not install properly. While not having it worked out I did a reboot.. now my ubuntu is not able to login with the message Sorry, that didnt work
If I try to login from the terminal, I get not further than filliing in the password. I get a message stating it cannot load a shared library for fingerprint-helper named libfprint.so.0. is there any solution to this?

Comment: Hey Mark, did you resolved this issue. I'm also facing the same issue now.